# [UIBarItem setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error, uitoolbar, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to give my UIToolBar a title, but when I try to add a UIBarItem with a title attribute, I get this error. My code:

```
UIBarItem *title = [[UIBarItem alloc] init];
title.title = @"My Title";

[toolBar setItems:@[cancel, title, ok]];
```

I've check the official docs for UIBarItem, and it does indeed have a perfectly valid "title" attribute. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i am not sure, have a try by changing the variable name to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, that `UIBarItem` is an **abstract superclass** of `UIBarButtonItem` and `UITabBarItem`.

Maybe the method is just declared in header and not implemented or the abstract implementation calls `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:`.

> `UIBarItem` is an abstract superclass for items added to a bar that appears at the bottom of the screen. …

For `-[UIToolbar items]` or <strike>`UINavigationBar`</strike> `-[UINavigationItem (left|right)BarButtonItems]`, you have to use use `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: For anyone trying this with a UINavigationBar, it really doesn't like UIBarButtonItem (unrecognized selector). So try a UINavigationItem instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, try making the object a button instead of just an item. This code worked fine for me

```
UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[title setTitle:@"My Title"];
```

If you're trying to give the toolbar a title, make a UILabel with the title and add it as a subview.

Comment: Those two calls are completely equivalent.

Comment: The difference between mine and his is that his is a `UIBarItem`, mine is a `UIBarButtonItem`. I tried it, his code didn't work, and when I tested mine it worked.

Comment: But OP wants a plain `UIBarItem`, doesn't he?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like you cant set the title for a `UIBarItem`, for some reason it gives an error. It might be a bug, but it doesn't work for some reason. I tried with dot-syntax and `[title setTitle:]`, but neither worked.

Comment: This answer does not explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007520-CH3-SW20):

> title
>
> The title displayed on the item.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title
> ```
>
> Discussion: You should set this property before adding the item to a
>   bar. The default value is nil.
>
> Availability: Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

So this title can indeed be set. Are you sure it is the `UIBarItem` class that is displayed as the part of the error message? Can be either a memory management problem, or if not, a bug in UIKit *(very unlikely)*.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should be using either `initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:` or `initWithTitle:image:tag:` to initialize your UIBarItem.

Comment: No. [The official documentation says the opposite.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007520-CH3-SW20)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at UITabBarItem.  UIBarItem is documented as an abstract superclass.

Comment: No problem, it's an understandable mistake :)

Comment: So, to reiterate - I think the problem is that your trying to instantiate an abstract class, which you shouldn't do, though I don't know offhand if it would cause the problem you're seeing.